# Obterner el total individual por registro

Tags: mysql

tengo la siguientes tablas :

```
                    REPORTEBETEITIVA
_______________________________________________________
|  idReporteBeteitiva   |    HorasTrabajo |Trabajador |  
-------------------------------------------------------
|        1              |         8       |     1     |
-------------------------------------------------------
|        2              |         8       |     1     |
-------------------------------------------------------
|        3              |        14       |     2     |
-------------------------------------------------------


                        TRABAJADOR
    ________________________________________
    |  idTrabajador   |  Nombre  |  Cedula |  
    ----------------------------------------
    |        1        |   PEDRO  | 1054632 |
    ----------------------------------------
    |        2        |   CAMILO | 1234555 |
    ----------------------------------------
```

Lo que deseo es que al momento de hacer la consulta se me sume por usuario el total de horas debajo de cada registro osea asi:

```
       ______________________
       |  Nombre |  HorasT  |   
       ----------------------
       |   Pedro |   16     |
       ----------------------
       |  TOTAL  |   16     | 
       ----------------------
       |  Camilo |   12     | 
       ----------------------
       |  TOTAL  |   12     | 
-----------------------------
|TOTAL           |   28     |
-----------------------------
```

Lo que quiero es que me muestre el resultado individual, solo lo he logrado lo siguiente:

```
       ______________________
       |  Nombre |  HorasT  |   
       ----------------------
       |   Pedro |   16     |
       ----------------------
       |  Camilo |   12     | 
-----------------------------
|TOTAL           |   28     |
-----------------------------
```

Mi consulta:

```
SELECT trabajador.Nombre, sum(HorasTrabajo) as HorasT FROM 
reportebeteitiva INNER JOIN trabajador ON reportebeteitiva.Trabajador = 
trabajador.idTrabajador group by trabajador.Cedula;
```

Gracias por la ayuda !!!

Comment: En tu resultado esperado, no entiendo porque sumas las horas de Pedro, te sale 16 y luego quieres poner TOTAL 16 otra vez justo debajo

Comment: Sinceramente no logro entender tu necesidad. veo que ya obtenes la suma de horas de cada empleado, entonces asumo que lo que queres es la suma global de horas por todos los empleados?

Answer (score 1):

Mira, creo que ya tenes lo que necesitas, el problema esta en la forma de mostrarlo, y eso lo tenes que hacer en el lenguaje de programacion que estes usando.

Comment: No amigo, lo que quiero es que todos los registros por ejemplo con las horas trabajadas de PEDRO se sumen como ya lo hice, pero por registro, osea que se muestre el total de horas debajo de PEDRO, el total de horas de CAMILO debajo del registro de CAMILO no al final de la columna.

Answer (score 0):

Lo tienes facil. lo unico que quieres son los mismos datos dos veces con nombres distintos.

```
SELECT * FROM (
    SELECT trabajador.Nombre, HorasTrabajo as HorasT FROM 
    reportebeteitiva INNER JOIN trabajador ON reportebeteitiva.Trabajador = 
    trabajador.idTrabajador group by trabajador.Cedula

    UNION

    SELECT trabajador.Nombre+'_TOTAL', sum(HorasTrabajo) as HorasT FROM 
    reportebeteitiva INNER JOIN trabajador ON reportebeteitiva.Trabajador = 
    trabajador.idTrabajador group by trabajador.Cedula

) T order by Nombre  WITH ROLLUP;
```

Aunque creo que no es necesario, y debes realizar lo en la vista.

Comment: La perte del total me la hace el `WITH ROLLUP` pero el rollup me lo hace hasta el final de la culumna y yo lo quiero es por cada registro

Comment: acabo de ver tu comentario. quita en la primera consulta el sum.

Answer (score 0):

Yo lo que haría sería: con una vista obtener las horas del trabajador 1, y otra vista con las horas del trabajador 2 para más tarde sumar el valor obtenido de las dos vistas.

Ejemplo:

```
create or replace view t1(horas1) as
SELECT sum(HorasTrabajo) as HorasT FROM 
reportebeteitiva INNER JOIN trabajador ON reportebeteitiva.Trabajador = 
trabajador.idTrabajador where trabajador.idTrabajador=1;

create or replace view t2(horas2) as
SELECT sum(HorasTrabajo) as HorasT FROM 
reportebeteitiva INNER JOIN trabajador ON reportebeteitiva.Trabajador = 
trabajador.idTrabajador where trabajador.idTrabajador=2;

select sum(horas1+horas2) as TOTAL from t1,t2;
```

Algo así sería mi idea, inténtalo y ya nos contarás a ver que tal te ha ido.

Un saludo.